# CXF REST APIs Documentation using Swagger

Tags: java, documentation-generation, api-design, swagger, cxfrs

According to Swagger's tutorial, seems [swagger](http://swagger.wordnik.com) only support [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) framework (See https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/java-jax-rs)

Does anybody have experience on making swagger work with [CXF JAX-RS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html) implementation? Could you share your suggestions here?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing the answer. Have you found out anything?

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-jaxrs-cxf) will be useful.

Comment: Thanks Lekkie, swagger provided sample for cxf.

Comment: I tried to access the link, but it no longer exists. I am having the same issue in creating cxf rest with swagger2feature :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use Swagger with CXF JAX-RS implementation using swagger-jaxrs_2.10 module.

Using Swagger in CXF environment require some specific configuration that can be done via Spring application context.

Here is a good [tutorial](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-CXF-Quickstart) and [example](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs-cxf) of such configuration.

Comment: The links are both defunct.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is possible to use swagger with Apache CXF. Below is the swagger usage in my working API.

```
@GET
    @Path("/version")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "For paged fetches returns a version for future fetches")
    public long version(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
        return ABC.version();
    }
```

Comment: Great, maybe you could show us how you did the integration?